# Unable to install Bootstrap 5.0.1 package in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8, bootstrap-5

**Laravel 8** moved to Tailwind instead of Bootstrap. As I need latest **Bootstrap** (**v5.0.1** so far) for my new project I added Bootstrap via `npm`, but it brings v4.6.0 instead of v5.0.1. I've tried updating the version number in composer.json and composer.lock (to ^5.0.0) before creating a new empty public/css/app.css and running `run dev`. I get v4.6.0 again!

Googling hasn't been a solution to find a clear explanation as how to update to latest Bootstrap package. I could add it as a custom css but I need it to go through *postcss* (which by the way has some unsolved issues so far) or similar CSS processor.

Tried clearing cache, just in case with no luck.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a video tutorial solving (almost totally) my question (Spanish): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXLiTcNIK2Q

Basically he installs bootstrap via `ui`. That installs v4.x.x as described in my question. Then he uses the following line: `npm install bootstrap@next`, which he gets from official Bootstrap website, despite I can't find it there anymore. The '@next' seems to do the trick but no clue about it, sorry.

That installed in my Laravel project bootstrap 5.0.0-beta3 (instead of latest 5.0.1, no clue either). Updating popper is what finally makes it all work.

In the video you can see how to install `bootstrap --auth`, too. But that was not part of my original question.

Despite I still don't know how to get to latest Bootstrap 5 version it solved my project so far. Any clues about that and about the '@next' bit are welcome.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Just use LATEST instead of NEXT.

`npm install bootstrap@latest bootstrap-icons @popperjs/core --save-dev`